# .SRT File Import Problem on Premiere Pro CC 2017 1.2

Tags: premiere, adobe, subtitles, .srt

I'm having some really strange behaviour of an .srt file when I import into a Premiere project.

First off, the .srt file defaults to 720 x 480 in size and 1000 fps. My project video settings are 23.976 fps. My sequence lasts 3:30:00 in duration but when I drag the .srt file over it only lasts 1:30:00. The timing info for all the subtitles are out of whack. When I modify the settings of the .srt file to 23.976 fps, the subtitles then extend to over 5 minutes.

To me, it's as if Premiere is not reading the data in the .srt file properly. Do I need to export it differently than just using Notepad (or similar), changing to unicode and saving the text as a .srt file? I really thought this would be a simple import functionality on Premiere but it's not.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

It's a Premiere bug. Try Subtitle Edit 3.5.5, which is free, insert the .srt, export as EBU STL file (25 fps works fine, it's time coded not frame coded).

Import to Premiere, interpret as open Captions, set the adequate resolution and..way you go. For problems with position of the titles and rows, play with 9 position squares in matrix (3 X 3), it will correct the position of both rows.

Comment: Is there any other subtitle format beside `EBU STL` that will allow closed captioning?

Answer (score 1):

So I found a workaround. I was importing .srt files developed through Rev.com and then was editing them in Premiere.

The problem was each file was imported as a default of 1000fps and 720x480. This caused issues in my 23.976fps and 1920x1080 based timeline. I basically just exported the .srt files as Timed Text Files (.xml) and made the timebase 23.976, then reimported the .xml files and applied them to my sequence instead. Simple but it fixed all of my flicker/crashing issues. To fix the resolution issue you can just right click the caption file in your timeline once it's dropped in and click "Scale to Frame Size". This should scale your image up to the correct size.

If when you import some of your text is scattered or laid in the wrong order, try selecting all of your captions and reposition using the 3x3 placement box in the caption panel. This should reset everything to look normal for you.